# MongoDB adding objectID from one collection to another

Tags: mongodb, foreign-keys, mongodb-query

I have mongodb `collection1` which looks as below

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7286c9bcf16750f621007b"),
        "host" : "host1",
        "column2" : "value2",
        "column3" : 6,
        "date_created" : "2015-01-25 00:00:00"
}
```

I have mongodb `collection2` which looks as below

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a728429bcf16750f62056e8"),
        "hostname" : "host1",
        "column2" : 322,
        "column3" : 81,
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a728429cde16750f62056e8"),
        "hostname" : "host1",
        "column2" : 312,
        "column3" : 89,
}
```

I want to add `field` in `collection2` named as `collection1_id` such that `hostname` in `collection2` matches `host` in `collection1`

My output should be as below

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a728429bcf16750f62056e8"),
        "hostname" : "host1",
        "column2" : 322,
        "column3" : 81,
        "collection1_id" : ObjectId("5a7286c9bcf16750f621007b")  

}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a728429cde16750f62056e8"),
        "hostname" : "host1",
        "column2" : 312,
        "column3" : 89,
        "collection1_id" : ObjectId("5a7286c9bcf16750f621007b") 
}
```

All I know at this point in time is I will need to run `db.collection2.update()`

Answer (score 0):

you can `$lookup` using aggregation pipeline and use the result cursor to update collection _id in collection2

pipeline

```
db.co2.aggregate(
    [
        {$lookup : {from : "co1", localField : "hostname", foreignField : "host", as : "collection1_id"}},
        {$addFields : {collection1_id : {$arrayElemAt : ["$collection1_id._id" , 0]}}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

result

```
> db.co2.aggregate([{$lookup : {from : "co1", localField : "hostname", foreignField : "host", as : "collection1_id"}},{$addFields : {collection1_id : {$arrayElemAt : ["$collection1_id._id" , 0]}}}]).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a728429bcf16750f62056e8"),
    "hostname" : "host1",
    "column2" : 322,
    "column3" : 81,
    "collection1_id" : ObjectId("5a7286c9bcf16750f621007b")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a728429cde16750f62056e8"),
    "hostname" : "host1",
    "column2" : 312,
    "column3" : 89,
    "collection1_id" : ObjectId("5a7286c9bcf16750f621007b")
}
>
```

**EDIT**

for mongo version 3.4 and lower

with `$project` instead of `$addFields`

```
db.co2.aggregate(
    [
        {$lookup : {from : "co1", localField : "hostname", foreignField : "host", as : "collection1_id"}},
        {$project : {hostname : 1, column2 : 1, column3 : 1, collection1_id : {$arrayElemAt : ["$collection1_id._id" , 0]}}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

Comment: getting an error `assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'",
        "code" : 16436
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:287:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: change `$addFields` to `$project`

Comment: I am getting output like `{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7286c9bcf16750f6210089"),
        "collection1_id" : ObjectId("5a72842bbcf16750f620ba02")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7286c9bcf16750f621008a"),
        "collection1_id" : ObjectId("5a72842bbcf16750f620e907")
}
Type "it" for more
`

Comment: `when I do find() on rows I don't see "collection1_id" : field`

Comment: `$project` will default output `_id` and other field specified in project, so we will get only `_id` and `collection1_id`, you need to add all other fields required in project, see `$project` documentation